# how to send data to php file then echo a message

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to send data to php file then echo the word "Hello!" when i call a function in javascript, however, no message appear, i guess there is en error in the calling, can you guide me please?

Here is my code:

Javascript:

```
function asyncpost_deviceprint() {
var xmlhttp = false;

if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
  xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else if (!xmlhttp) return false;

xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost/Assignment/insert.php", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

xmlhttp.send("userAgent" + userAgent()); /*  fire and forget */
return true;
```

}

PHP:

```
<?php
     echo "Hello!";
?>
```

Comment: Where do you want the message to appear? You aren't doing anything with the response that the PHP script is sending you.

Comment: Here's some [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) - I recommend you read it to understand how to use `XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass JavaScript variables to PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-to-pass-javascript-variables-to-php)

Comment: for now i am not concerned with the data a send, i am wondering how i make the "Hello!" string appear when the "insert.php" file after being called.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "Hello!";
```

won't display any message because in Ajax request this function sends a respond to Javascript.
If you want to display sth on the screen with PHP instead of Ajax you should use:

```
window.location.href="path to your php site"
```

it will redirect you to php file and display Hello!

Answer (score 0):

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4) {
        if (xmlhttp.status === 200) {
            document.body.innerHTML += xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
};
```

Add this before `xmlhttp.send`

It will literally just stick the php echo text after the last thing in the document.